# How to use recursive makefile

Tags: recursion, makefile

I want to build hierarchical compile my c-codes using makefile.
But it does not work.

Of course I already read recursive usage in http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Recursion and I just follow the example.

```
SUBDIRS = test_A test_B

.PHONY: run_subdir $(SUBDIRS)
run_subdir: ${SUBDIRS}

${SUBDIRS}:
    ${make} -C $@
```

C test_A

> make: C: Command not found makefile:7: recipe for target 'test_A'
>
> failed make: [test_A] Error 127 (ignored)

C test_B

> make: C: Command not found makefile:7: recipe for target 'test_B'
>
> failed make: [test_B] Error 127 (ignored)

Comment: You should read your [link](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Recursion) more carefully.  It says `$(MAKE)` not `${make}` -- case is important.

Comment: oops, Thank you for your comment. It miss the character case.

Comment: It is better to use non-recursive approach. I recommend you to use a ready made solution for that https://github.com/igagis/prorab it has tutorials also.